# 'invalid iteration specific' error on Julia

Tags: signal-processing, julia

I'm trying to implement the MUSIC algorithm and I chose Julia to write my code.

```html
DOA=ones(1,rand(1:10))
 for i in 1:length(DOA)
    DOA[1,i]=rand(0:1000)*pi/180;
 end
 sensors=11;
 freq=ones(1,length(DOA[1,:]))
 for i in 1:length(DOA)
   freq[1,i]=rand()*pi*100;
 end
 signals=length(DOA);
 lambda=100;
 dist=lambda/2;
 A=zeros(signals,sensors);
 snr1=rand(20:40);
 N=200;
 x=zeros(length(freq),N);
 for j = 1:length(freq), for k = 1:signals
    x[j,k]=2*exp(im*freq[j]*k);
 end
 for l = 1:signals, for m = 1:sensors
    A[l,m]=exp(-im*2*pi*dist*sin(DOA[1,l])*m/lambda));
 end
```

So `for j = 1:length(freq), for k = 1:signals` shows no error but the one after, `for l = 1:signals, for m = 1:sensors`, keeps showing the 'invalid iteration specification' error.
My novice tries include, commenting the for loop, deleting it completely and giving spaces in between just to see what was going on. Surprisingly, even after I saved the file numerous times and started a new bash session it showed me the same error for a commented for loop and blank spaces. Any ideas about tackling this problem? Or better yet, what can cause such errors? I've attached a screenshot too for the specifics, line 38 being the for loop with the error.

[image: I've attached a screenshot too for the specifics, line 38 being the for loop with the error.]

Answer (score 1):

You can either use one multidimensional `for` loop using commas, e.g.,

```
for i = a:b, j = c:d
    ... 
end
```

or multiple separate `for` loops without commas, e.g.,

```
for i = a:b 
    for j = c:d
        ... 
    end
end
```

Note that within a comprehension, these forms are different

```
julia> [(i,j) for i = 1:2 for j = 4:5]
4-element Array{Tuple{Int64,Int64},1}:
(1, 4)
(1, 5)
(2, 4)
(2, 5)

julia> [(i,j) for i = 1:2, j = 4:5]
2×2 Array{Tuple{Int64,Int64},2}:
(1, 4)  (1, 5)
(2, 4)  (2, 5)
```

Comment: Thanks for the input! So i reconstructed the loop and it's expression. Weirdly the loop worked without the 'im' constant. Any idea how? The exponential worked on the REPL when I tried 'exp(im)'

Comment: I didn't go through your code in detail, but one problem is that you try to assign complex numbers to the arrays `x` and `A` which have the element type `Float64`. Did you mean to initialize these arrays as `zeros(Complex{Float64}, dims...)`?